# Select json values from array in Oracle 19c table

Tags: arrays, json, oracle

Newer to working with JSON and newly upgraded Oracle 19c DB.
I'm receiving a JSON array back from an api and storing it in an Oracle 19c table column with IS JSON (STRICT) constraint.

```
[ {"key1":"valueA", "key2":"valueB"}, {"key1":"valueC", "key2":"valueD"} ]
```

I need to select values in column form:

```
KEY1    KEY2
valueA  valueB
valueC  valueD
```

This returns one row with null columns.

```
Select jt.* 
  From json_data, 
       json_table(myData, '$.[*]' 
       columns( key1, key2)) jt;
```

I can't seem to make the Oracle functions (json_table, json_query, json_value, ...) handle this without wrapping the array in an object.

```
{ "base":[ {"key1":"valueA", "key2":"valueB"}, {"key1":"valueC", "key2":"valueD"} ] }
```

Then this query works:

```
Select jt.* 
  From json_data, 
       json_table(myData, '$.base[*]' 
       columns( key1, key2)) jt;
```

Is there a shortcoming with the Oracle functions or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `$[*]` not `$.[*]`

```sql
SELECT jt.* 
FROM   json_data
       CROSS APPLY json_table(
         myData,
         '$[*]' 
         columns(
           key1,
           key2
         )
       ) jt;
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE json_data ( myData VARCHAR2(2000) CHECK( myData IS JSON(STRICT) ) );

INSERT INTO json_data ( myData )
VALUES ( '[ {"key1":"valueA", "key2":"valueB"}, {"key1":"valueC", "key2":"valueD"} ]' );
```

Outputs:

> | KEY1 | KEY2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | valueA | valueB |
> | valueC | valueD |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5be0bddd4d1a4ddd257065314bfaf354)*

Comment: I KNEW I must be doing some dang little thing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Select jt.* 
  From json_data, 
       json_table(myData, '$[*]' 
       columns( key1, key2)) jt;
```

Full test case with results:

```sql
with json_data(myData) as (
select '[ {"key1":"valueA", "key2":"valueB"}, {"key1":"valueC", "key2":"valueD"} ]' from dual
)
Select jt.* 
  From json_data, 
       json_table(myData, '$[*]' 
       columns( key1, key2)) jt;

KEY1                 KEY2
-------------------- --------------------
valueA               valueB
valueC               valueD
```

Comment: I KNEW I must be doing some dang little thing wrong.
THANK YOU